# Determining thread performance

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, cpu-usage

On some machines, my .Net application is idling at ~10% CPU usage.  My first inclination is that one of my background worker threads is executing some instructions that I'm not aware of, but I don't know how to isolate CPU usage by thread (Task Manager simply tells me that my process uses *x* number of threads [usually around 30], not which threads are hogging CPU).

I know that programmatically I can iterate through the threads as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/102556/1265219) but I don't know if that will give me the information I need.  Is there a profiler (commercial or otherwise) that will allow me analyze CPU usage per thread?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 has a good profiler built in, at least in the Ultimate edition. As a poor man's solution, you could try randomly pausing your code in the debugger, and see where it breaks. At 10% CPU usage, you should have a 1 in 10 chance to find the guilty code (or more if you have a multicore machine).

Comment: 10% while idle? Select 'Find in files' and look for Sleep(1)/Sleep(0) <g>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend [JetTrace dotTrace Performance](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/). It will tell you where your code is spending most of its time, as well as the thread. (It is commercial but comes with a free 10 day trial.)

Comment: It's only a 10-days free trial ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try Perfview from Microsoft: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567

You can use system ETW events to figure out lots of low CPU utilization issues.

Comment: This looks pretty promising.  I can tell it's definitely a Dev-made tool cause it's usability is super lacking :)

Comment: It's developed by VanceM (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/), Architect on the .NET Runtime Team

Answer (score 1):

How about attaching a debugger and hitting the "break" button. Then just see if any of the threads are running in your code?

Comment: Ah, my assumption was that you didn't own all 30 of the threads, and that most of the threads would be sitting idle or on a sleep or wait statement of some sort. If all the threads are "running" why wouldn't CPU usage be at 100%?

Comment: Well, they are "alive", but I wouldn't assume they are running.  I understand your point a little more now.  I'll give it a whirl and see what I can find, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I second [NominSim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11634779/107625) and would recommend [Red Gate's ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/). Helped me a lot in the past.

They do have a 14-days free trial version.

Comment: I've used ANTS, but the .net 4.0 CAPSOL changes really screwed their awesome profiling power.  I still have a license for it, but I wasn't aware of how to get real time CPU usage of individual threads.  I'll go check the documentation.  Thanks!